# Implement sound in sweetalert popup

Tags: audio, popup, sweetalert

English is not my mother tongue, please excuse any errors on my part.

Is it possible to implement an audio file in swalfire popup. I would have an notification/sound during this popup:

```
Swal.fire({
  title: 'Custom width, padding, background.',
  width: 600,
  padding: '3em',
  background: '#fff url(/images/trees.png)',
  backdrop: `
    rgba(0,0,123,0.4)
    url("/images/nyan-cat.gif")
    left top
    no-repeat
  `
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
var soundfile = "sounds/RedAlert.mp3";
Swal.fire({
                title: 'Your Title!',
                html: 'Text or Content',
                confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-primary',
                confirmButtonText: 'Your Text',
                buttonsStyling: false,
                onOpen: function () {
                    var audplay = new Audio(soundfile)
                    audplay.play();
                }
            })
```

Comment: Thanks, for the first step. Is it possible to stop the audiofile when I close the swal-fire?
Is this solution onyl for chrome?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).